# Three-level nested logit in R

Tags: r, logistic

Is there a package that performs three-level nested logit in R? I've looked at the `mlogit` package, but didn't see a three-level example.

Comment: you may have better luck with biogeme, another open source and widely used program for GEV models: http://biogeme.epfl.ch/